# show commits done to the git branch between two instances

Tags: git, logging, branch, commit

I had a release branch which was created from develop branch. After which other developers made commits to both branches parallely. Few days ago the release branch was merged back into develop and closed.

Now We need to know all those commits that are done to "develop" between creation of release branch and closing it.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

A simple, but effective way to find the branch start/end points to diff is to view the repo tree "graphically" - and it is easy to see all the commits:

```
git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline
```

Then look at where your branch split off and re-joined.

Then simply do a diff on the short-hash:

```
git diff 1a2b3c4 1a2b3c4
```

if you just want to see the files quickly:

```
git diff 1a2b3c4 1a2b3c4 --name-only
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the old [`hub compare`](https://github.com/mislav/hub/blob/31fbabbbc9e0746fc12dd304e6c9f5d7df55299c/hub-compare.1.html#L94-L127) is now obsolete, you can use [`gh browse-compare`](https://github.com/kyanny/gh-browse-compare) instead, which is a [gh CLI extension](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/working-with-us.md#step-0-create-an-extension).

It addresses [`cli/cli` issue 4433: "Add "compare" command"](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/4433).

```bash
gh extension install kyanny/gh-browse-compare
gh alias set compare 'browse-compare'

# git clone https://github.com/django/django.git
# cd django

gh compare 3.2.8...stable/3.2.x
# => it opens https://github.com/django/django/compare/3.2.8...stable/3.2.x

# In your case
gh compare <hash-where-release-branched-off>..<hash-where-release-merged-back>
```

But that would only open the comparison on GitHub, not provide a detailed list of commits directly in the terminal.
It would open a browser window with the GitHub comparison view, which will list the commits between the two points.

---

Instead, for a list of commits:

```bash
git merge-base develop release
git log --oneline --graph --all # => identify the commit hash 
                                # where the release branch was merged back 
                                # into the develop branch
# or, to identify the merge back commit:
git switch develop
git log --merges --grep="Merge branch 'release'" --oneline

# Finally
git log <common-ancestor-hash>..<merge-commit-hash> --first-parent develop
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the SHA from `develop` just after you split off `release`
2. Get the SHA from `develop` just before you merged `release` back in

Plug them into the git /compare interface for your repo: `https://github.com/<org name>/<repo name>/compare` Ex: https://github.com/github/hub/compare

Example of a compare with SHAs filled in: https://github.com/github/hub/compare/f93e53798ff87c3ba0e99858812fc89b27e3a54b...3d3facba2c53cc62669e5166435ae350847faa88

Alternatively, you could run `git log <first sha> ^<second sha>^` This should include all commits between the two SHAs, including the start and end commits themselves. But you may find the compare more helpful, as it handles merge commits more gracefully.