# Comparison Tool in GitHub (compare releases, or shas if necessary)

Tags: git, github, diff

Can someone recommend a comparison tool/add-on/ in GitHub.  I'd like to see the code changes between two particular releases.  It would be nice if it showed all the files that have changed and I could then drill down into each file of interest.

This link:
https://github.com/blog/612-introducing-github-compare-view
said there already is one in GitHub, but I can't see the "compare" button they refer to.  The post is from 2010 so perhaps the feature was removed.

If there is nothing in for GitHub, perhaps some direction on just using Git to list all the files that have changed between the two releases.  Then I'd need a way to see what those changes are for each file.  Frankly though, this seems like something that would be a pain on the command line!

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: You do have the option of `git diff commitA commitB` from the CLI, any GH features aside.

Comment: Note that requesting software recommendations is offtopic.

Comment: I don't use github much so can't answer your main question; but as to how to do it with git command line: `git diff --name-status releaseA releaseB` will get the summary (changed files, quick view of lines added/removed/changed), and `git diff releaseA releaseB -- path/to/file` will drill down to see the patch to a file (for ascii / text type files)

Comment: Thanks Mark!  That's helpful.  In the case of many files, a visual tree that one can drill down on would be helpful.

Comment: There are a number of great diff viewer out there. Since you are using github, you might want to add `.diff` to your release comparison, e.g. https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v5.0.2.rc1...v5.0.2.diff. After saving is from the browser or `curl`ing it into a file, you can then use your favourite diff/patch viewer, Maybe you'll find one here: https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-file-diff-tools-comparison/

Answer (score 3):

Starting January 2020, you now have "[a shortcut to compare across two releases](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-01-13-shortcut-to-compare-across-two-releases/)":

> You can now compare tags between two releases – in order to determine what changes have been made – by clicking on the <kbd>Compare ▾</kbd> button for a given release.

[image: GitHub Release Comparison]

That give you a URL like https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/compare/v1.11.0-rc1...release/v1.11

---

Oct. 2023, you also have [`gh compare`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77240004/6309)

Answer (score 1):

Github supports the split view in compare pages. Just add `?diff=split` to the url and you'll be fine. E.g. https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v5.0.2.rc1...v5.0.2?diff=split.
Github remembers your preferred comparison view. To reset it, write `?diff=unified` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone recommend a comparison tool/add-on/ in GitHub. 
>   I can't see the "compare" button they refer to.

Append `/compare` to your repository's path to enter the compare view.